# Как отправить данные в GET-запросе в Django

Tags: django

```
Хочу отправить на сервер example.ru данные "login: qwe, pass: word". Юзаю urllib, urllib2
data = [('login','qwe'),('pass','word')]
r = urllib2.urlopen('example.ru',urllib.urlencode(data))
Если данные не передавать, то всё ок. Если передавать - HTTPError 403 Not forbidden. В allowed hosts добавил себя.
```

Comment: Месье знает толк в извращениях. И, позвольте спросить, зачем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите передать GET - делайте так:

```
urllib2.urlopen('http://example.ru?%s' % urllib.urlencode(data))
```

если у urlopen передан второй аргумент, он будет отправлять POST запрос

http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло :)